# What could be causing an uneven roll at low speeds?

Tags: tires

I've noticed that my car has an uneven roll at very low speeds, almost as if one of the tires is being favored. Is this likely to be an issue with a tire or are there other potential issues?

Comment: Check Proper tire inflation.

Comment: What kind of car? Is it 2WD or 4WD/AWD? Does it have ABS?

Answer (score 1):

Belt shift is a common cause of low speed squirm. To find the offending tire or tires, raise each tire off the ground and rotate slowly by hand. You are looking for a shift in the tread usually a small area covering less than 12 inches. The shift may be less than an inch side to side. It is caused by the steel belts under the tread shifting after the tire was made. It is difficult to prove it is a manufacturing defect as impact with a pothole can cause the same symptoms.